# Containers that can hold H264 encoded video

Tags: delphi, encoding, containers, h.264, matroska

How can I use Matroska container to save H264 video? I have been looking for examples but I have found none. Maybe I am searching with wrong parameters. Can anyone point me in right direction? I have looked at Matroska source but it seems overkill to study the whole source code to accomplish this. There should be a practical way to do it.

Comment: Are you sure it already has such capabilities?

Comment: Well, I think I just found what I have been looking for: http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html It takes time to convert from C to Pascal though.

Answer (score 2):

Working with DirectShow you could use the [Matroska Muxer filter](http://matroska.org/downloads/windows.html)

or you could dump to an avi then use ffmpeg to copy the stream(s) to an mkv

```
ffmpeg -i <input_file> -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mkv
```

Comment: Or you can use ffmpeg programmatically, it's available for Delphi. (http://www.iversenit.dk/dev/ffmpeg-headers/). Though requires older version of the dlls (the ones specified in the headers).